# La moitié des participants sera ou seront récompensé(e)/(s)

Tags: grammaire, expressions, conjugaison

Admettons que nous sommes dans un tournoi et que nous voulions récompenser la moitié des personnes présentes.

Doit-on dire

> La moitié des participants sera récompensée
>
> -> C'est-à-dire qu'on récompense la moitié

OU

> La moitié des participants seront récompensés
>
> -> C'est-à-dire que ce sont les participants qui seront récompensés

---

*Personnellement, je trouve la deuxième forme plus adaptée au contexte, mais sur de nombreuses affiches, on voit plutôt "sera récompensée".*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu fais ce que tu veux, cela dépend de ce que tu tiens à mettre en valeur. La proportion ou les participants.

En cas de fractions ou pourcentages, les seuls cas obligés sont :

- Si la fraction est précédée d'un article au pluriel (*Les deux tiers* -> pluriel)
- Dans le cas où la fraction est précédée de *plus* -> accord avec le complément. (*Plus de la moitié des participants seront... / Plus de la moitié du globe est...*)

<sub>NDaCOSwt: Tu verras effectivement sur des pubs l'accord fait sur le singulier (c'est à dire avec la moitié) parce que le public a coutume de n'avoir qu'une chance sur +mille+ de gagner. Si tu offres en fait une chance sur deux, alors cela peut valoir le coup d'insister sur le rapport plutôt que sur les participants.</sub>

Comment: merci pour cette information. Tout dépend donc de ce que nous voulons mettre en valeur

Answer (score 2):

L'accord doit se faire suivant le bon sens. Le bon sens n'interdit pas le singulier si l'on souhaite mettre l'accent sur *la moitié* mais pourra recommander le pluriel en raison de la présence du déterminant pluriel *des*.

Références (c'est moi qui souligne):

---

> Accord sujet/verbe
>
> Le verbe conjugué doit s'accorder en nombre et personne avec son sujet. Dans le
>   cas de sujets coordonnés, d'adverbes de quantité ou de structures complexes, cet
>   accord peut poser problème.
>   ...
>   4. Lorsque le sujet est introduit par la plupart ou peu de, le verbe se met au
>   pluriel ; pour les autres collectifs, l'accord se fait selon le bon sens.
>   **La plupart des étudiants ont compris**.
>   Beaucoup de patience est nécessaire pour réussir.
>   Une troupe de touristes est sortie de l'hôtel.

*Le bon usage*, Maurice Grevisse et André Goosse

---

> Accord avec un sujet singulier ayant un sens pluriel
>
> Certains noms ou locutions au singulier peuvent avoir un sens pluriel. Dans ce cas, l'hésitation est fréquente sur l'accord du verbe ou de l'adjectif.
>
> Ainsi doit-on dire : La foule des spectateurs est arrivée ou sont arrivés ? La moitié des invités est venue ou sont venus ?
>
> Le plus souvent, il s'agit en fait d'un choix de sens ou d'intention, laissé à l'appréciation de celui qui s'exprime : l'accord peut se faire soit avec le sujet collectif au singulier si l'on privilégie l'idée d'ensemble (vision globale), soit avec le complément au pluriel si l'on pense à une pluralité d'unités (vision détaillée).
>   ...
>   Les noms de fraction
>
> L'accord se fait soit avec l'expression de la fraction ou du pourcentage (c'est le plus souvent le cas quand celle-ci désigne une quantité exacte), soit avec le complément (notamment quand il s'agit d'une évaluation approximative ou quand l'expression de la fraction ou du pourcentage est précédée d'un déterminant pluriel).
>
> La moitié des intervenants a plus de quarante ans mais **La moitié des intervenants sont des hommes** (à cause de l'attribut pluriel des hommes).

[Parler français](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/accord-c690993)

> Nom collectif suivi d’un complément au pluriel (accord du verbe)
>
> Ce problème d’accord se présente dans de nombreux cas où le sujet est formé d’un nom et de ce qu’on peut appeler, suivant la terminologie du Bon Usage de Maurice Grevisse, un « pseudo-complément » :  **l’accord se fait soit avec le nom, soit avec son « pseudo-complément », selon que celui-ci ou celui-là frappe le plus l’esprit, et que l’on considère les êtres ou les objets dont il s’agit, ou bien comme formant essentiellement un ensemble, ou bien en détail, dans leur pluralité**. Ainsi : Une foule de malades accourait (c’est une foule qui accourt) mais : Une foule de gens diront qu’il n’en est rien (chacun d’eux dira…). Dans ce dernier cas, la subordination logique l’emportant sur la subordination grammaticale, on parlera d’accord par syllepse. Cet accord par syllepse est parfois obligatoire : après la plupart, ainsi que nombre et quantité, employés sans déterminant, l’accord se fait avec le « pseudo-complément ». Dans le cas d’ensemble, on écrira aussi bien : l’ensemble des intéressés a ou ont protesté.
>
> L’accord dépend du sens des mots, mais aussi de l’intention de l’auteur. On trouvera donc : Un grand nombre de soldats fut tué dans ce combat (Littré) et Un grand nombre de soldats périrent dans ce combat (Académie).
>
> En particulier dans le cas d’un nom numéral au singulier suivi d’un complément au pluriel, l’accord peut se faire avec ce complément ou avec le terme quantitatif quand la personne qui écrit arrête son attention sur celui-ci plutôt que sur son complément. L’Académie admet les deux possibilités : Une quinzaine de francs suffira ou suffiront pour sa dépense.

[Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue)

---

> Fraction et pourcentage
>
> Après l’expression d’une fraction ou d’un pourcentage suivis d’un complément, l’accord du verbe peut se faire au singulier ou au pluriel, selon le sens ou l’importance qu’on accorde à la proportion exprimée par la fraction ou le pourcentage, ou à l’ensemble exprimé par le complément. Dans ce dernier cas, un complément au pluriel entraîne un verbe au pluriel, tandis qu’un complément au singulier entraîne un verbe au singulier.
>   ...
>   Exemples :
>   ...
>   –  **La moitié des députés a voté** pour le projet. (On insiste sur une fraction précise.)
>   –  **La moitié des pommes seront vendues**. (On met l’accent sur le complément, féminin pluriel.)

[OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1597)

Answer (score 1):

D'un point de vue grammatical, il est correct de dire « la moitié des participants sera récompensée » parce que le nom principal du sujet de la phrase c'est *moitié*, le terme *des participants* n'étant qu'un accompagnant. Il faut aussi faire l'accord de genre du nom avec le verbe, donc « récompensé**e** ».

Comment: c'est-à-dire on peut dire "la moitié sera récompensée" les participants pouvant être enlevé.
Mais si on l'ajoute, on récompense plutôt les participants et pas la moitié. Je confonds peut être avec "c'est qui que je récompense : les participants".
Quand vous dites " Il faut aussi faire l'accord de genre du nom avec le verbe" vous considérez que le nom est "moitié"

Comment: Tu ne réponds à la question qu'à moitié...

Comment: Et il faut donc d'après toi dire : « la moitié des êtres humains est une femme »...

Comment: @jlliagre Pas « une », « des » ; « La moitié des êtres humains est **des** femmes. »; encore un exemple : « La poussière est des particules très fines. »

Comment: @LPH Je m'étonne que tu défendes ici, en prenant beaucoup de libertés avec l'usage, une réponse dont tu contredis pourtant la substance dans ta propre réponse.

Answer (score -3):

Il n'est pas exact de dire que « moitié » est  « récompensée » ; il s'agit de la « moitié des participants » ; le sujet apparent est  « moitié des participants ». La construction est comme suit : « sujet apparent/verbe passif » ; dans ces conditions, de quoi fait partie l'élément « des participants » si on ne le place pas dans le sujet ?

La question est de savoir comment faire l'accord ; traditionnellement l'accord a été décidé comme devant être fait avec le mot principal du syntagme ; c'est pour cela que non seulement sur de nombreuses affiches mais dans toute la littérature du français c'est cette règle qui est appliquée. L'accord grammatical n'est pas représentatif d'un nombre réel : le processus de « distribution » sur l'ensemble que signifie « moitié des participants » est très bien compris. La politique de tolérer n'importe quoi ne solutionne rien et pour l'instant c'est la règle traditionnelle qui devrait prévaloir, jusqu'à une résolution raisonnable de la question. Ce qui est en faute ce n'est pas tel ou tel accord mais la conception de « l'ensemble pluriel », la définition de ce qui est pluriel.

Si l'on veut un accord avec « participants » il y a la possibilité de changer la forme;

> Des participants, au nombre de la moitié, seront récompensés.

Il n'y a plus aucun problème ; ce qui est en faute c'est la conception du syntagme dont le mot principal doit être « participants » et non « moitié », lequel n'est qu'une spécification.

Il existe sans aucun doute des possibilités pour réparer cette erreur de nos ancêtres et il ne faut pas croire que la solution rationnelle au problème consiste à laisser faire en comptant que par une succession complètement aléatoire d'essais de ci et de ça au fil des ans et décennies émergera un jour comme par enchantement la réponse finale.